# I was trying to add fragment via xml and print data fetched from fragment to MainActivity,but the code isn't running

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments

Main Activity XML File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.harsh1507.pc.t_1372.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/l1">

        <fragment
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:name="com.harsh1507.pc.t_1372.Frag_a"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/tv"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Main Activity JAVA File

```
package com.harsh1507.pc.t_1372;

import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Frag_a.comm 
{
    TextView tv;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        tv= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
    }

    @Override
    public void com(double s) {
        tv.setText("Result is : "+Double.toString(s));
    }
}
```

Fragment XML File

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:context="com.harsh1507.pc.t_1372.Frag_a">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:id="@+id/ed1"/>

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/ed2"
            android:inputType="number"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="cal"
            android:id="@+id/btn"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RadioGroup
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/rg"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="ADD"
                android:checked="true"
                android:id="@+id/rb1"/>

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="SUBSTRACT"
                android:id="@+id/rb2"/>

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="MULTIPLY"
                android:id="@+id/rb3"/>

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="DIVIDE"
                android:id="@+id/rb4"/>

        </RadioGroup>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Fragment JAVA File ,main problem may be present in this part but i am not able to debug that ,please go through the code and let me know where i missed something.

```
package com.harsh1507.pc.t_1372;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.IdRes;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class Frag_a extends Fragment
{
    View v;
    comm c;
    EditText ed1,ed2;
    Button btn;
    RadioGroup rg;
    RadioButton rb1,rb2,rb3,rb4;
    double d1,d2,comp;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) 
    {
        super.onAttach(context);
        c=(comm) context;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        v= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_frag_a, container, false);
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        ed1=v.findViewById(R.id.ed1);
        ed2=v.findViewById(R.id.ed2);
        btn=v.findViewById(R.id.btn);
        rb1=v.findViewById(R.id.rb1);
        rb2=v.findViewById(R.id.rb2);
        rb3=v.findViewById(R.id.rb3);
        rb4=v.findViewById(R.id.rb4);
        rg= v.findViewById(R.id.rg);
        d1=Double.parseDouble(ed1.getText().toString());
        d2=Double.parseDouble(ed2.getText().toString());

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (rb1.isChecked()) {
                    comp = d1 + d2;
                    c.com(comp);
                }
                if (rb2.isChecked()) {
                    comp = d1 - d2;
                    c.com(comp);
                }
                if (rb3.isChecked()) {
                    comp = d1 * d2;
                    c.com(comp);
                }
                if (rb4.isChecked()) {
                    comp = d1 / d2;
                    c.com(comp);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public interface comm{
        void com(double s);
    }
}
```

Comment: where are u adding the fragment???

Comment: @AvinashRoy fragment is added in Main Activity XML File.

Comment: is it giving compile time error?

Comment: Could it be a problem caused by using both the v4 and v7 support libs? Try making the main activity a (v4) FragmentActivity.

Comment: @SagarPujari the app is stopping in my mobile before launching.

Comment: @FrankkieNL can u please give any example.

Comment: @H.Singh1507 I have executed your code its working for me. Though it gave me exception on   d1=Double.parseDouble(ed1.getText().toString());d2=Double.parseDouble(ed2.getText().toString()); So i removed that code and run the code and it worked.

Comment: So what might be the error in my case ,is it my IDE which is not wroking properly or something else. What do u recommend me to do with the code, as it still giving error on removing Double..... .

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that ur main activity extends FragmentActivity instead of AppCompat.

The corresponding import would be :

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
```

Any activities using fragments must be implemented as a subclass of FragmentActivity instead of the traditional Activity class

Comment: AppCompat is imported by default so i should remove that,don't u think other functionaliteis will get affected.

Comment: i extended FragmentActivity instead of AppCompat but its still stopping.